# Find the System Name, IP Address and other information in SQL Server who dropped or altered stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing an issue that someone or some how some of my stored procedures were deleted or dropped. Now, I need to know how to find the user, system name (PC Name, Application Name or other) IP Address of that person who have dropped/deleted those stored procedures from my database.

I have generated the schema change report from SQL Server from which, I can see the user Name who dropped the stored procedure with drop time.

Now, I need to find the system name, IP and other information if it is possible.

Report from SQL Server (this is a demo from SQL Server where I have found change schema report. I can share the original report)

[image]

I appreciate you help and response. Please, let me know if any information is required to this question. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** the stored procedures were deleted 3 days ago, when I have found that issue.

Comment: Dear, @marc_s Sir, I am expecting help from you. Thank you for editing my post.

Comment: `sys.traces` will give you the file name of the default trace; `fn_trace_gettable` can then be used to get the data yourself. IP address is not included, but the user name, host name and application name are. Do note that host and application name are supplied by clients and thus subject to spoofing, making it unsuitable for security auditing, but good enough if you just need a stick to beat a careless user with.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for you information. The problem is that, I can not get the file from the server due to permission. So, I can not do that. Is there any other way to do that.

Comment: There is no permissions issue since the server can always read its own trace files. You do need permission to execute `fn_trace_gettable`, but if you can run that report you should already have that. There is no need to copy the trace files locally or somesuch (although that is a good idea if you want the information later, because eventually this trace data will roll over and you'll lose it).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for your time. Can you post an answer with example and steps.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate in detail what @Jeroen Mostert has mentioned...

You can get lot of information from Administrative log/trace file.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_trace_getinfo(NULL)
WHERE property = 2 AND traceid = 1
```

Above query will return trace file location. Once you get that you can run another query to extract information from trace file. E.g. (Replace "...trc" with actual file name with full path)

```
SELECT * FROM fn_trace_gettable('...trc', -1)
WHERE EventClass = 47 AND ObjectType = 8272
```

You can refer following links to apply more filter criteria as per your need.

Link for [Deleted Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/object-deleted-event-class?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)

Link for [Object Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/objecttype-trace-event-column?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)